# join XML Elements and handle if not exits - using Linq-to-XML ASP.Net C#

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

Extending to my own question from [My Earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995686/query-nested-xml-elements-using-linq-to-xml-asp-net-c-sharp)

If you notice i am joining my elements with **let** keyword

some times my XML may not have all these elements.

So is it possible to join this element on if exits?
if not exists give a **null or empty** value for that field

for example if there is no **Pharmacy Element.**

then this  `let Pharmacy = MD.Element(NameSpace + "Pharmacy")`
should be possible and this

```
phStoreName = Pharmacy.Element(NameSpace + "StoreName").Value,
```

should give me a **null or empty** value for **phStoreName**

```
var MedicationDispensed =
  (from MD in xdoc.Descendants(NameSpace + "MedicationDispensed")
   let DrugCoded = MD.Element(NameSpace + "DrugCoded")
   let Quantity = MD.Element(NameSpace + "Quantity")
   let Pharmacy = MD.Element(NameSpace + "Pharmacy")
   let phIdentification = Pharmacy.Element(NameSpace + "Identification")
   let phAddress = Pharmacy.Element(NameSpace + "Address")
   let phPhoneNumbers = Pharmacy.Element(NameSpace + "PhoneNumbers")
   let phPhone = phPhoneNumbers.Element(NameSpace + "Phone")
   let Prescriber = MD.Element(NameSpace + "Prescriber")
   let prIdentification = Prescriber.Element(NameSpace + "Identification")
   let prName = Prescriber.Element(NameSpace + "Name")
   let prAddress = Prescriber.Element(NameSpace + "Address")
   select new
   {
       DrugDescription = MD.Element(NameSpace + "DrugDescription").Value,
       ProductCode = DrugCoded.Element(NameSpace + "ProductCode").Value,
       ProductCodeQualifier = DrugCoded.Element(NameSpace + "ProductCodeQualifier").Value,
       Qualifier = Quantity.Element(NameSpace + "Qualifier").Value,
       Value = Quantity.Element(NameSpace + "Value").Value,
       CodeListQualifier = Quantity.Element(NameSpace + "CodeListQualifier").Value,
       DaysSupply = MD.Element(NameSpace + "DaysSupply").Value,
       LastFillDate = MD.Element(NameSpace + "LastFillDate").Value,
       phStoreName = Pharmacy.Element(NameSpace + "StoreName").Value,
       phNCPDPID = phIdentification.Element(NameSpace + "NCPDPID").Value,
       phAddress1 = phAddress.Element(NameSpace + "AddressLine1").Value,
       phCity = phAddress.Element(NameSpace + "City").Value,
       phState = phAddress.Element(NameSpace + "State").Value,
       phZipcode = phAddress.Element(NameSpace + "ZipCode").Value,
       phPhoneNumber = phPhone.Element(NameSpace + "Number").Value,
       phQualifier = phPhone.Element(NameSpace + "Qualifier").Value,
       prDEANumber = prIdentification.Element(NameSpace + "DEANumber").Value,
       prLastName = prName.Element(NameSpace + "LastName").Value,
       prFirstName = prName.Element(NameSpace + "FirstName").Value,
       prMiddleName = prName.Element(NameSpace + "MiddleName").Value,
       prAddress1 = prAddress.Element(NameSpace + "AddressLine1").Value,
       prCity = prAddress.Element(NameSpace + "City").Value,
       prState = prAddress.Element(NameSpace + "State").Value,
       prZipCode = prAddress.Element(NameSpace + "ZipCode").Value
   }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution to deal with it Referring to this [Link](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2007/12/05/use-the-power-of-let-in-your-linq-queries.aspx)

```
    What if "let" returns null?

If you declare an object with "let" such as

let myPayment = bill.Element("payment")

select new Payment

  {

     Amount = (decimal) myPayment.Element("Amount")

  }

If myPayment is null, this blows up with a null reference exception.  The alternative would be

  Amount = myPayment != null ? (decimal) myPayment.Element("Amount")

but think how cumbersome that is for a bunch of fields.

What's the solution?
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this:

```
Pharmacy.Element(NameSpace + "StoreName").Value
```

use explicit conversion operator like this:

```
(string)Pharmacy.Element(NameSpace + "StoreName")
```

It will return .Value if the element is not null or an empty string if the element does not exist. Here you can find more details about explicit conversion operators for XElement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.op_explicit.aspx

Comment: well this may work at select level but i have problem with joining elements. how can i join the elements which may or may not exits.